# PHP mysqli Test Run

Tags: php, mysql, testing, command-line, mysqli

I have a PHP script with one select query and several prepared update statements. Is there a way to run the script in test mode so that no changes are written to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the whole thing in a transaction, and then rollback the transaction after the other test queries are done.

That, or you dump out the table(s) involved, and restore the dump after each test, so you keep the environment consistent between each run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transactions with commit and rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.
I suggest making a backup of the data.
Add one thing, restore the backup to see if your change was reversed and do the test run knowing that you have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a test run should be run on, well, a test-database, where you can run the queries unhindered.

However, if all your queries mutating data are on InnoDB / transactions-aware tables, and no query issues an implicit commit, you could wrap them in a transaction and roll them back / just not commit them.

Comment: I don't want to destroy my test database... let's just forget about how test databases should be easy to create for this question. :)

Comment: Hehe, they should :P. But OK. go with the now thrice mentioned transactions if you really can't ;).